# Data redundancy for order

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Table **order_detail:**

> order_no  | product_id

Table **product_detail:**

> prod_id | prod_name | prod_size | prod_type

```
order_detail .product_id  references to product_detail.prod_id
```

I heard data redundancy is a bad idea, so I inner join the tables to display the complete order details. But the problem is the data inside `product_detail` can be edit or delete by admin, which means when I inner join the tables, it might return `null`. Should I store something like JSON example: `{size:23,type:MZ}` in the `order_detail` to avoid the data 'loss'?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` on `order_detail`

Comment: Doesn't look like admin is doing a good job.

Comment: You should make sure the database won't allow partial deletion of data, or modification of data that affects other parts. If you make an order and someone changes the product, that changes every order that references the data and that probably isn't good. Reducing redundancy must not be done at the expense of data integrity.

Comment: If your `admin` (just an user of your program IMO) can delete the product detail even when there is/are order(s) on that product, then your business logic (BL) have problems. That BL make data `loss`. IMO you should talk to your team to change it ASAP.

Comment: Re "I heard data redundancy is a bad idea": "Data redundancy" means nothing in particular. Don't worry about rumours, educate yourself. Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.)

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to break down your table structure.**

Having to store data in JSON format in your `order_detail` table compromises [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on your database(which is not desirable).

**Make product attributes as individual entities.**

- **Product_detail**

> id | name | some_other_descriptive_columns | deleted_at

- **Product_Type:**

> id | type

- **Product_size:**

> id | size

- **Product_type_mapping:**(pivot table which signifies many-to-many relationship between products and it's types)

> id | product_id | product_type_id | deleted_at

- **Product_size_mapping:**(pivot table which signifies many-to-many relationship between products and it's sizes)

> id | product_id | product_size_id | deleted_at

- As you might have already noticed, we have an additional column called `deleted_at` whose datatype will be a `timestamp` and which is `nullable` by default in all the tables shown above.
- When the admin edits(could also be removal of certain sizes or types) or deletes a product, all we do is make an entry of a timestamp in `deleted_at` column. In other words, we do a **soft delete**.
- So, when the admin operates on a product data set, fetch all the details whose `deleted_at` column IS NULL. When doing an inner join to fetch order details, it would not hinder the process of losing any data even if admin deletes a product after a few days after an order was made, because we would fetch all details regardless of what we have in our `deleted_at` column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider using a schema like the one in the diagram. (The arrowheads are the "many" end of the PK-FK relationships.)

This approach maintains referential integrity and avoids the use of nulls by recording deletions in a separate table.

You might also want to add a "ProductDataChangedOnDate" feature that keeps a record of the changes made by that pesky admin person :-)

[image: 5NF solution]